# Looking to complete two equations and use results for final in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if this can be done in one swoop, but I think it would be nice. 
I need to calculate the following

> (ORank×60%)+(CRank×40%)=PScore
>
> (BRank×60%)+(ARank×40%)=NScore
>
> PScore−NScore=CScore

CScore is my ultimate need. But I need to use the data found in one table to give me this results.

I know that this can be done one by one but not advanced enough in my skill set to know if this can be done at once.

EDIT:

SO now a follow up.. I want to get the AVG I used SELECT AVG (((ORank*.6)+(CRank*.4))-((BRank*.6)+(ARank*.4))) AS CScore FROM table... but that seems to maybe not be correct at the avg should only be between -1 to 1 but I am getting 2.16 Am I formatting the AVG wrong with this query ? The lowest number on the CScore is -0.998701054845278 and highest is 0.99946494141603

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hoping this isn't deceptively simple...

I assume that these ranks are columns and not calculated.  if so, simple algebraic substitution says that:

```
CScore = (((ORank*.6)+(CRank*.4))-((BRank*.6)+(ARank*.4)))
```

So...

```
SELECT (((ORank*.6)+(CRank*.4))-((BRank*.6)+(ARank*.4))) AS CScore
FROM table...
```

If the ranks are instead calculated and you don't care about performance, you could do (nasty-looking) subselects or joins.

Comment: Ok cool will give this a shot.. don't need joins as all of this is in one table.. but then again I am new so I could be uninformed of the full potential of joins.

Comment: SO now a follow up.. I want to get the AVG I used SELECT  AVG (((ORank*.6)+(CRank*.4))-((BRank*.6)+(ARank*.4))) AS CScore
FROM table... but that seems to maybe not be correct at the avg should only be between -1 to 1 but I am getting 2.16 Am I formatting the AVG wrong with this query ?

Comment: Don't see anything obviously wrong; what average do you get if you pull all the rows (or some subset, like LIMIT 10000) and calculate by hand?

Comment: I didn't do it manually but I have have done an ASC on the output and the highest number is -0.998701054845278 so I know the AVG I see of 2.16 can't be correct.